# Rails 4 Active Record finder method

Tags: activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4, dynamic-finders

I have a Rails 3 Active Record  finder method and i am trying update it to rails 4 patten.

In Rails 3, my code looked like this

```
StripeEvent.setup do
  subscribe 'customer.subscription.deleted' do |event|
    user = User.find_by_customer_id(event.data.object.customer)
    user.expire
  end
end
```

In Rails 4, i tried this, is this piece of code correct?

```
StripeEvent.setup do
  subscribe 'customer.subscription.deleted' do |event|
    user = User.where(customer_id: (event.data.object.customer) )
    user.expire
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It am unclear why you choose to fetch records in this way when you can do

```
user = User.find_by_customer_id(event.data.object.customer)
```

Comment: So does rails 4 still support this find_by_customer_id ?

Comment: Yes, Dynamic attribute-based finders [http://api.rubyonrails.org/](http://api.rubyonrails.org/) are still supported. You can use either the form I have mentioned or the following User.find_by(customer_id: event.data.object.customer)

Comment: please consider accepting the answer if you are satisfied with it or ask for more details

Answer (score -1):

The `find_by_*` is deprecated.

In Rails 4, please use `find_by` like so:

```
User.find_by(customer_id: event.data.object.customer)
```

You can read more about Deprecated Finders in this great blog post: [What's new in Active Record [Rails 4 Countdown to 2013] | The Remarkable Labs Blog](http://blog.remarkablelabs.com/2012/12/what-s-new-in-active-record-rails-4-countdown-to-2013). Or checkout CodeSchool's [Rails 4: Zombie Outlaws](http://rails4.codeschool.com/videos) course.

Comment: This is incorrect. The only deprecated finders are `find_all_by_...` `find_last_by_...` `find_or_create_by_...` `find_or_initialize_by_...` `scoped_by_...`